# insert data into tables from form django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to insert data from form into database. Following are the models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
# Create your models here.

class Recipe(models.Model):
title=models.CharField(max_length=200)

class User(models.Model):
fname=models.CharField(max_length=30)
lname=models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Recipe2User(models.Model):
user_id=models.ForeignKey(User)
recipe_id=models.ForeignKey(Recipe)

class Ingredient(models.Model):
recipe_id=models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
name=models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Prepration_step(models.Model):
recipe_id=models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
step=models.CharField(max_length=1000)

class RecipeForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model=Recipe
 fields=['title']
```

I have created a form which takes recipe name, ingredients and preparation steps.
Below is the view which handles the post:

```
def createRecipe_form(request):
  c = {}
  c.update(csrf(request))
  return render_to_response('create.html',c)

def create_recipe(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form=RecipeForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
         title=form.cleaned_data['recipe_name']
         r=Recipe(title)
         r.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect('display.html')
       else:
         form=RecipeForm()
         return  render(request, 'create.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

and this is the html form I have created

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Create-Recipe</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>My Recipe-Create a recipe</h1>
        <form action="/recipe/submit-recipe/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
          {% if errors %}
         <div id="errors">
            <ul>
        {% for error in errors %}
        <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </div>
{% endif %}
    Title:
    <input type="text" name="recipe_name" placeholder="Ex:Gobi Masala"><br>

    Ingredient:
    <textarea rows="4" name="recipe_ingredient" cols="50" placeholder="Ex: 2 cups rice,1/2 teaspoon oil"></textarea><br>

    Preparation:
    <textarea rows="4" name="recipe_preparation" cols="50" placeholder="Ex:Pour oil in frying pan,Fry onions till they turn light brown"></textarea><br>

    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

Please tell me how to go about inserting recipe title, ingredients and steps in Recipe, Ingredient and Prepration_step table as I am newbie to django.
Thanks

Comment: i have created only html form and the in models.py RecipeForm is incomplete. i dont knw how to go about it. please guide me

Answer (score 1):

**forms.py**

```
class RecipeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
```

**views.py**

```
def create_recipe(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form=RecipeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app_name:url_name'))
    return  render(request, 'create.html', {
        'form': RecipeForm(),
    })
```

**html**

```
<form action="/recipe/submit-recipe/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

Comment: so RecipeForm should be in forms.py and not models.py rite?

Comment: you can put form in your model but that is a bad practice in Django. You have to separate it to make it arrange

Comment: ok thank you. but as you can see the Recipe model has only name. i need to also add ingredient and prep_steps to db which are differenet models

Comment: you can use formsets but it difficult in your part. Just select other forms for that

Comment: any suggestions for changing the models, so that it becomes easier for me to insert data

Comment: The scenario will be after the user save recipe name, it will reverse to add ingredients page. The user will add new ingredients for that recipe

Comment: Why you have recipe and recipe2? What can recipe2 can do? listing?

Comment: recipe2users maps recipe and users, so that we know which users has posted which recipe and in html i can see only the submit button

Comment: If that's the case just erase Recipe2 and put user field in Recipe

Comment: in html i can see only the submit button and can you please guide me in creating the form so that i can input recipe title , ingredients and preparation steps in form

Comment: it's hard to guide you in here where making long conversations,, maybe you can send your codes in my gmail and I will fix it

Comment: catherinetenajeros@gmail.com

Comment: I will just message you if I finish, I will just having my dinner